# How to save the button that has been added dynamically in Android?

Tags: android

I know how to dynamically add a button, but how can I save it so I can see it when I restart the app?

```java
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
LinearLayout linaer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1); 
btn.setId(count);
final int id_ = btn.getId();
btn.setText(editText.getText().toString());

//**linaer.addView(btn, params);**

Button btns = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
btns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent it = new Intent();
        it.setClass(MainActivity.this, Album_Main.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you reopen the app won't same code get executed again and button would be created?

Comment: no.. when reopen the app I want to see the  button created last time..

Comment: How do you know if its a newly created button or the old one?

Comment: In test, I created a button , I can see it and use it. But after reopen the app the button disappear

Comment: Well I don't think its possible. Adding button from xml is probably the best idea.

Comment: Ok... so i can just use the setVisibility method, right?

Comment: Can you give us a more info? Like what the buttons are supposed to do, or why would you need those buttons created on the fly

Comment: I an trying  to build albums and that's why I need the buttons still there after reopen

Comment: I think you should use a RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

When you create a button keep the flag of it and when you reopen your app just check that flag. If it matches your condition create a button which you want.

Comment: It would be better to just check if the button exists rather than create a flag for it. Try to stay away from flags.